# APERTIUM PYTHON: Translation from Spanish to Catalan

Tags: python, translation, apertium

I am a complete newbie trying to use Apertium for translating Spanish short strings to Catalan, however I get the following warning:

`lt-proc: invalid option -- 'x'`

I have read that that's common in the Python module and is not deeply worrying, however, the problem comes with the following minimal example:

```
import apertium
# apertium.installer.install_module("spa-cat")
t = apertium.Translator('spa', 'cat')
print(t.translate('Coche rojo.',mark_unknown=False))
```

That prints:

`^Cotxe/*Cotxe$ ^vermell/*vermell$.`

Altough it seems to be translating ok ("Coche rojo" = "Cotxe vermell") I can't find why all those symbols are appearing and why the words are repeated. This doesn't happen to me when I use other translation pairs such as English-Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y lttoolbox
```

And then re-installing all the languages via:

```
import apertium
apertium.installer.install_module("spa")
apertium.installer.install_module("cat")
apertium.installer.install_module("spa-cat")
```

With this, both the warning and the inconvenient symbols went away.